# PHP File Upload Script Produces Blurry Image

Tags: php, file-upload

The file uploading script I have made, uploads a blurry image when uploaded! This is my current script, try to figure out what I have done wrong. The script uploads the images as .png, with username being the actual username of the current logged in user.

Please note that the original image is 17x22, so that isn't whats making it blurry.

```
<?php
include('../class/resize.php');
//error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
$path = "../files/cloaks/"; //set your folder path
$filename = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name']; //get the temporary uploaded image name
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "jpeg","GIF","JPG","PNG", "JPEG"); //add the formats you want to upload

        $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name']; //get the name of the image
        $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size']; //get the size of the image
        if(strlen($name)) //check if the file is selected or cancelled after pressing the browse button. 
        {
            list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name); //extract the name and extension of the image
            if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) //if the file is valid go on.
            {
            if($size < 2098888) // check if the file size is more than 2 mb
            {
            $actual_image_name =  $_POST['fname']; //actual image name going to store in your folder
            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name']; 
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name)) //check the path if it is fine
                {   
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name); //move the file to the folder
                    $dburl = ('../files/cloaks/'.$actual_image_name.'');
                    $image = new ZiResize();
                    $image->load($dburl);
                    $image->resize(22,17);
                    $image->save($path.$actual_image_name);
                    //display the image after successfully upload
                    echo "<img src='files/cloaks/".$actual_image_name."'  class='preview'> <input type='hidden' name='actual_image_name' id='actual_image_name' value='$actual_image_name' />";

                }
            else
                {
                echo "failed";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error! Max image size is 2 MB!";                  
            }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error! Invalid image format!";    
            }
        }
        else
        {       
        echo "Error! No file selected!";
        }       
    exit;
    }
?>
```

resize.php code

```
<?php
class ZiResize {

   var $image;
   var $image_type;

   function load($filename) {

      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }
   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         imagegif($this->image,$filename);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         imagepng($this->image,$filename);
      }
      if( $permissions != null) {

         chmod($filename,$permissions);
      }
   }
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         imagegif($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         imagepng($this->image);
      }
   }
   function getWidth() {

      return imagesx($this->image);
   }
   function getHeight() {

      return imagesy($this->image);
   }
   function resizeToHeight($height) {

      $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resizeToWidth($width) {
      $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
      $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function scale($scale) {
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreate($width, $height); 
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
   }      

}
?>
```

Comment: The problem will be in your `ZiResize` class. Maybe check out its documentation. Can you show an example screen shot?

Comment: A example screen shot of what exactly? The resize code?

Comment: What is this doing? Could be re-sizing it so the image gets blurred `$image->resize(22,17)`

Comment: You'll need to check the documentation of the `ZiResize` class to see if you can change the sampling algorythm. I'm assuming 22 and 17 are the dimensions of the output - any image resized that small will be blurry anyway.

Comment: No, the image is a pixelated picture, it only needs the image to get those pixels.

Comment: @user2140088 What others are saying is that none of your code is modifying the image, other than `ZiResize`. Therefore, if you're having issues with how the image looks, why not look into the one piece of code that is, well, actually _doing_ something with the image.

Comment: How would I remove the part where its modifying the image then? Ive added the other code btw.

Comment: remove `$image->resize(22,17);` ... but then, you could remove the whole class and just copy original image to destination

Comment: Ive already tried that @Buksy, it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `compression` argument when you are saving the image

`function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null)`

You are using jpg format, in php, you can set quality of result image, if that quality is lower then original image, the image will look "blurred" even though it hasn't been resized.

You can:

1. Change compression value ( `$image->save($path.$actual_image_name, NULL, 100);`
2. Change format of image to other format that doesn't support "compression"

As you are not resizing the image, you can replace this:

```
$image->resize(22,17);
$image->save($path.$actual_image_name);
```

with this:

```
$image->save($path.$actual_image_name, NULL, 100);
```

Comment: Im uploading a .png file, not a jpg.

Comment: Yes, but you are saving a `jpg` file. Just try to replace code as I written and it should help, let me know if not ..

Answer (score 0):

your resizing to 22px by 17px. it will always look blury when you reduce an image to that size. you should also use `imagecreatetruecolor` as it allows a full colour spectrum. imagecreate is limited in its colours, which is another reason the image could look blury

Comment: No, the original image is 22px by 17px. Its not being resized, it would even be fine if someone could remove the resizing part for me, as I had trouble doing it myself.

Comment: updated answer, replace `imagecreate` with `imagecreatetruecolor` in your resize function

Comment: Do I have to do this to all of the "imagecreate"s?

Comment: to resize the image or resample, yes. but for a simple file uploader, none of the image load or resize or manipulation needs to be there at all

Comment: Actually this helped me out a bit having it save at a better quality, however it didn't fix the issue, but Im using it in my code right now! Thank you for your help!